# How to check django staff user first time login in admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am working on a django project and I am using the default auth app for authentication.
I know that there is a `last_login` field in user model which stores the user's last login time.

When a staff user logs in first time into the admin panel, I want to check if `last_login` field is none & redirect him to the change password page.

Where should I put this check?

---

**What I have tried so far:**

I have tried to use a custom login form and override the default `confirm_login_allowed` method on it, but it seems like I can only raise a validation error to block login attempt using these.

I also tried using `django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in` Signal but that also does not allow me to return a redirect response when `last_login` is `None`.

I want to know how I can return a redirect response after the user has been authenticated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django admin is not that configurable. You should hook into its internal views. Login/logout views are inside Django `AdminSite` class (the one you usually access by `admin.site`). My implementation is a bit hacky but small:

Paste at the top of `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def login(self, request, extra_context=None):
        new_user = False
        user = None

        username = request.POST.get('username')  # Hack to find user before its last_login set to now.
        if username:
            user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
            if user:
                new_user = user.last_login is None

        r = super(MyAdminSite, self).login(request, extra_context)

        if new_user and request.user == user and isinstance(r, HttpResponseRedirect):  # Successful logins will result in a redirect.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:password_change'))
        return r

admin.site = MyAdminSite()
```

If you want a cleaner solution I suggest to use a boolean inside user model instead of relying on `last_login` so you could just check `request.user` instead of my hack into `request.POST`.

You could read `AdminSite.login` and `django.contrib.auth.views.login` to see what is actually happening inside Django.

Answer (score 5):

Customise Django admin using `AdminSite` and use login_form attribute to give the custom login form for the Admin login page.

admin.py

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    login_form = CustomAdminLoginForm

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
admin_site.register(User)
admin_site.register(Group
```

urls.py

When overriding the Admin we have to get rid of Django default admin

```
from app.admin import admin_site

url(r'^admin/', admin_site.urls)
```

forms.py

[AuthenticationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) have the `confirm_login_allowed` method use this to grant permission to login in or not login in.

```
class CustomAdminLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if user.last_login:
            raise ValidationError(mark_safe('Hey first time user please reset your password here... <a href="/test">test</a>'), code='inactive')
```

Note: There is lot of edge cases you have to consider for this approach.

1. What if user not set the password in the first time and how you're going to handle second attempt..? This time last_long not None. Although `date_joined` comes rescue. `last_login == date_joined`
2. But What if the user not set the password in first day and comes next day ?

Edit:

You can use signal to check the logged in user and apply the `config_login_allowed` logic here...?

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in


def change_password_first_time(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # Your business logic here...

user_logged_in.connect(change_password_first_time)
```

Comment: `confirm_login_allowed` may help in case i need to block the user from loggin in, however, i dont want that, i want the user to be logged in and then be taken to the change password page.

Comment: Ah I see.. May be you can use `user_logged_in` signal... I've updated my anwer

Comment: Ok, this might work, but what if my udpate password is a model admin method,  how do i call the model admin method in the connect fucntion ? 
I will be needing an instance to model admin to call its method.

`def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=''):`

Comment: Using signal's may not work as i need to redirect the user to a diffrent URL.

Comment: Oh sorry I'm out of options. May be try to update your question and draw SO users to answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

It was a big problem for me at once. I found a way to do it easy. Create a different variable to save the value of the users logged in data, when user is trying to login.

Below is my code:

```
if user.last_login is None:
   auth.login(request,user)
   return redirect(alertPassword) 

# when user is login for the first time it will pass a value

else:
   auth.login(request,user)
   return redirect(moveToLogin)

def moveToLogin(request):
   return render(request,"home.html")

def alertPassword(request):
   first_login=True
   return render(request,"home.html",{"first_login":first_login})
#it will pass a value to the template called first login is True
```

Then go to your template and add this:

```
{% if first_login==True%}
# Put anything you want to be done 
# In my case I wanted to open a new window by using script.
<script>

    window.open("popUpWindow")

</script>
{%endif%}
```